# Computing a derivative of map from $V \to V^*$ (PDEs and regularity)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading Rogers and Renardy book on parabolic regularity. There they consider a PDE
$$\dot u = A(t)u + f(t)$$ where $A(t):V \to V^*$ is an operator. In the regularity result, they need $A \in C^1(0,T;\mathcal{L}(V,V^*))$. So for a differentiable $A$, I want to compute its time derivative (wrt. $t$).

For example, let $V=H^1(\Omega)$, what is the derivative of $A(t)$ when $A(t)u = c(x,t)u$ where $c$ is some nice coefficient? Is it just $c_t(x,t)$? But $u = u(x,t)$ is really a function of time as well so do I take that into account? But looking at the domain and range of $A(t)$, I am not sure whether to take $t$ to be fixed in some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to find the derivative of $A(t)$, you should not differentiate $u$.

Consider for instance $y'=t^2y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the computation of $a'(t)=2t$ has nothing to do with $y'$.

Now if $A(x,t)$ depends also on $x$, the derivative with respect to $t$ is indeed $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}$. To compute this, you fix $x$, not $t$.